# Target first and second occurrence of Div on page using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I am trying to target the first and second occurrence of a div class on a page, I have the following but this does not work?

```
  var first = ($("#area").find(".cArea")[0]);
  var second = ($("aArea").find(".cArea")[1]);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Post your HTML as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`:eq(index)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to get directly the first and second one.

```
var first = ($("#area").find(".cArea:eq(0)"));
var second = ($("aArea").find(".cArea:eq(1)"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`:lt()`](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector to achieve this. It selects the elements in a collection whose index is lower than a provided value.

```
var $firstAndSecond = $('#area .cArea:lt(2)');
```